# How to put three floated div with different widths?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Look at the next image. I drew three rectangules (black, red and yellow) and each one receives different widths:

[image]

First column: 33%
Segund column: Remaining width (?)
Third column: 15px;

All of them are float. My first try was putting the first two columns, but was not a big deal (putting 66% in the second), but when I introduced the third column, I got trouble. I´m not sure what approach could I use to deal with these widths.

This is the DOM I have created:

```
<article class="cart-item">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="images/item1.jpg"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <h4 class="title">Dexter Men's Max Bowling Shoes (Right Handed Only)</h4>
        <span class="description">Shipping 3-day with UPS</span>
        <span class="description">Color: Gray</span>
        <span class="description">Size: 28.5</span>
        <span class="price">$60.00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
    </div>
</article>
```

Some of the CSS I have:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.center{
    float: left;
    width: ?;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;;
}
```

Comment: "Trouble"? What would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First column: 33% Second column: Remaining width (?) Third column:
>   15px;
>
> All of them are float.

If you are stuck up with `float` and cannot change the markup, then a simple `calc` would serve your purpose. But, that will introduce other problems. You will need to specify the height of the container, otherwise getting the images to align will become a nightmare for you. Especially the last one.

It will look something like this:

```
.cart-item {
    width: 320px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.cart-item > div { float: left; height: 100%; }
.cart-item .left { width: 33%; border: 1px solid #333; }
.cart-item .right { width: 15px; border: 1px solid #ee3;  }
.cart-item .center { 
    width: calc(100% - 33% - 15px); 
    border: 1px solid #e66;
}
```

**Demo Fiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3sz149f0/**

**Demo Snippet 1:**

```css
.cart-item, .cart-item * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.cart-item {
    width: 320px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.cart-item > div { float: left; height: 100%; }
.cart-item .left { width: 33%; border: 1px solid #333; }
.cart-item .right { width: 15px; border: 1px solid #ee3;  }
.cart-item .center { 
    width: calc(100% - 33% - 15px); 
    border: 1px solid #e66;
}
```

```html
<article class="cart-item">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64x64/66c"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <h4 class="title">Dexter Men's Max Bowling Shoes (Right Handed Only)</h4>
        <span class="description">Shipping 3-day with UPS</span>
        <span class="description">Color: Gray</span>
        <span class="description">Size: 28.5</span>
        <span class="price">$60.00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
    </div>
</article>
```

---

If you can change the markup and styles, then do not use `float`. Just use a table layout and then it would be super easy for you to arrange the content without relying on explicit height on the container.

It will look something like this:

```
.cart-item {
    display: table;
    width: 320px; overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.cart-item > div { 
    display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; 
}
.cart-item .left { width: 33%; border: 1px solid #333; }
.cart-item .right { width: 15px; border: 1px solid #ee3; }
.cart-item .center { 
    width: calc(100% - 33% - 15px); 
    border: 1px solid #e66; text-align: left; 
}
```

**Demo Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/d1qdyxrf/**

**Demo Snippet 2:**

```css
.cart-item, .cart-item * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.cart-item {
    display: table;
    width: 320px; overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.cart-item > div { 
    display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; 
}
.cart-item .left { width: 33%; border: 1px solid #333; }
.cart-item .right { width: 15px; border: 1px solid #ee3; }
.cart-item .center { 
    width: calc(100% - 33% - 15px); 
    border: 1px solid #e66; text-align: left; 
}
```

```html
<article class="cart-item">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64x64/66c"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <h4 class="title">Dexter Men's Max Bowling Shoes (Right Handed Only)</h4>
        <span class="description">Shipping 3-day with UPS</span>
        <span class="description">Color: Gray</span>
        <span class="description">Size: 28.5</span>
        <span class="price">$60.00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <img src="//placehold.it/6x32/666"></img>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div.center { width: calc(66% - 45px); }
```

45px = 30px padding + 15px width of right column